# How does DateAdd remove the filter from other date table columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table visual with following columns:

Year, Month, TotalCases

I created a new measure:

```
Test = CALCULATE(SUM(FACTSALES['TOTALCASES']), DATEADD(DATETBL['date'], -1, Month))
```

When I add this measure to the above table visual, then it does work, but my question is - how does it remove the filter from the year and month?

I was expecting that it needs `REMOVEFILTERS(DATETBL)` as well.

Note:

- I have auto date time disabled
- I have a date table but it's not marked as a date table (because it holds the data for multiple client calendars)

Answer (score 1):

DAX Time Intelligence functions are very useful and essentially provide sugarcoating to much more long-winded expressions.

For example, when using `DATEADD(DATETBL['date'], -1, Month)` it is doing the following in pseudo code:

- Get the min and max of `DATETBL['date']`
- Subtract a month from the min and max
- Then it does `ALL(DATETBL)` which removes all filters, and then it filters on the min/max from the previous step.

Hopefully this helps answer your question.

Comment: DateAdd is not a time intelligence function is it? Because the primary requirement of time intelligence function is the presence of table marked as date table. Whereas DateAdd works even without a table marked as date table (even when auto date time is off)

Comment: Regarding your other point that `ALL(DATETBL['date'])` - how does this remove the filter from the year and month?

Comment: That's not true. You don't have to have a table marked as a date table for it to work. You can use these functions on any date column. Some of the functions do depend on having consecutive dates in that column though. `ALL` returns the whole table or column, regardless of filters. Perhaps I mistyped the answer and it should of been `ALL(DATETBL) `. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: `DATEADD` is indeed a time intelligence function.